# ML.Net AutoML is getting null reference exception even though I have data?

Tags: c#, ml.net, automl

I am learning ML.Net and trying to use the AutoML API and getting a null reference exception. Question has been updated with my recent learnings and a minimal amount of code to reproduce.

Put this in VSCode and you too can experience a 2 dimension vector exploding.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mlContext = new MLContext();

        // create schema for multidimensional vector
        var autoSchema = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(InputData));
        var col = autoSchema[1];
        col.ColumnType = new VectorDataViewType(NumberDataViewType.Single, 3, 60);

        // fabricate some data
        var trainingData = new List<InputData>();
        var inputData = new InputData();
        inputData.MultiDimensional = new float[20,20];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputData.MultiDimensional.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputData.MultiDimensional.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                inputData.MultiDimensional[i,j] = 5; // doesn't matter
            }
        }
        trainingData.Add(inputData);

        // setup a data view
        IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<InputData>(trainingData, autoSchema);

        // preview it (goes BOOM)
        var preview = trainingDataView.Preview();

        // run the experiment
        var settings = new BinaryExperimentSettings();
        settings.MaxExperimentTimeInSeconds = 60;
        ExperimentResult<BinaryClassificationMetrics> experimentResult = mlContext.Auto()
            .CreateBinaryClassificationExperiment(settings)
            .Execute(trainingDataView);
    }
}

public class InputData
{
    public bool Label { get; set; }
    public float[,] MultiDimensional { get; set; }
}
```

The documentation seems to indicate my setup is correct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.data.vectortypeattribute.-ctor?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_Data_VectorTypeAttribute__ctor_System_Int32___

To fix my multidimension vector problem, I've tried:

- Removing the `float[,]` initializers in `InputData`
- Specifying the exact size with `[VectorType(3,60)]` as appropriate for each property
- Leaving the `[VectorType]` attribute off altogether and using autoschema to set it.
- Leaving the `[VectorType]` attribute off altogether and not using autoschema to let ML.net figure it out on its own
- Adding just `[VectorType()]`, although the docs say that is for single dimension arrays.

My question now is - what is the correct way to use vectors with more than 1 dimension in the AutoML part of ML.Net? Is this even possible?

Comment: Just curious, is there an error in loading the enumerable without the `autoSchema` parameter?

Comment: That's a great suggestion! I tried it out, same exception though.

Comment: What happens if you do `trainingDataView.Preview()`? Also, is it possible to get a sample of the data?

Comment: Interesting - I got the same exception with doing Preview. I just now tried adding a [NoColumn] attribute on all multidimensional vectors, and the exception goes away. Is there something I'm doing wrong with these? It seems correct from the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.data.vectortypeattribute.-ctor?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_Data_VectorTypeAttribute__ctor_System_Int32___

Comment: Good find! I saw you put an issue in [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5446). Hopefully the team can have a fix for you soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow, found my own question years later still open. From the github issue posted in the comments, this still is not possible. This [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/6066) in 2022 confirms this is still the case.